# Escape a url within a regular expression in a preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, urlencode

I am trying to redirect some  tags to another page, passing its href as a url parameter. The code I'm using is something like this:

```
preg_replace(
    "/<a(\s[^>]*)href=[\"\']??([^\" >]*?)[\"\']??([^>]*)>(.*)<\/a>/siU", 
    "<a$1href=\"".WWW."go.php?to=".urlencode("$2")."\"$3>$4</a>", $text
);
```

It is a modified version of the regexp found [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/). I use this code in this block:

```
$text = "<...some other tags...><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.google.com\" style=\"...\" class=\"...\">Google</a></...some other tags...>";
```

And it correctly gets captured, but when using `urlencode("$2")`, it recieves a `"$2"` string, and not the value stored in the preg variables (as I would). It is not limited to urlencode, but to passing this as a parameter to any other function. So I would not only want to encode this (I can always extend a little more the regexp to accept urls) but generally use variables inside methods.

Do you know any workaround to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using a preg_match to get the goodies, then processing them with urlencode. Finally, compile the link and do a str_replace.

Comment: you should have a look at preg_replace_callback for this

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher I already though about that, I was just trying to exhaust any other solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is totally normal as your are url encoding the string "$2" and then the urlencoded string is used for replacement so you end up with the same thing as writing

```
"<a$1href=\"".WWW."go.php?to=$2\"$3>$4</a>"
```

as second parameter. If you want the urlencode to be evaluated you have to use the e (for eval) flag like this:

```
preg_replace(
    "/<a(\s[^>]*)href=[\"\']??([^\" >]*?)[\"\']??([^>]*)>(.*)<\/a>/seiU", 
    "'<a$1href=\"'.WWW.'go.php?to=\"'.urlencode('$2').'\"$3>$4</a>'", $text
);
```

another preferable solution may be to use preg_replace_callback to avoid relying on evaluating unknown strings

Comment: preg_replace_callback was the perfect solution to me. Thanks a lot!